# Wordpress custom endpoint api for register new users [rest_no_route]

Tags: wordpress, api, rest

i'm tryng to make an endpoint to make registration avviable througth api in my Wordpress site.
i've developed the following code but when i try to call the api throuth postman i get this error "rest_no_route".
I've created my own plugin in the plugin folder in my wp-content and put this script there.

That's my code:

```
add_action('rest-api-init', function (){
    register_rest_route('custom/v1', '/register',array(
        'methods' => 'POST',
        'callback' => 'api_register_new_user',
        'permission_callback' => function () {
            return true;
        }
    ));
});

function api_register_new_user(WP_REST_Request $request): object
{
    $response = (object)[] ;
    $body = $request.get_body();
    $body = json_encode($body);
    $user = register_new_user(body['username'],$body['password']);
    if(! is_wp_error($user)){
        $response->status = 200;
        $response->message = "OK";
        $response->data->user_id = $user;
    }else{
        $response->status = 501;
        $response->message = $user;
        $response->data->user_id = "";
    }
    return $response;
}
```

Comment: `add_action('rest-api-init', ...)` should be `add_action('rest_api_init',...)`. Mind the underscores vs the hyphens in action name.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i lose a day in this error

Comment: Glad it helped. I've posted my suggestion as answer so that you can accept it as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`add_action('rest-api-init', ...)` should be `add_action('rest_api_init',...)`. Mind the underscores vs the hyphens in action name.